# angular2 where i will get all packages at one place

Tags: angular2-template

I saw one online  video  in that video he show package.json,system.config.json,tsconfig.json,typing.json files at one place. In that video he displays url `https://angular.io/guide/quickstart` .But when i searched that url there is not available coukd you please reffer me that url path

Comment: If you are new to Angular 2 then it is recommended to use [Angular CLI](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html) for the development. As it will give you everything you need. And to learn angular2 simply visit[angular.io](https://angular.io) site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install angular QuickStart. Click on this link [Setup a local development environment](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html) and flow the steps of this article.

Hope so it will work successfully.

Thanks!